# How to read data in MapDB files

Tags: java, mapdb

Is there a way to see the data saved in MapDB files like I do with MySQL? I'm putting some data in a ConcurrentNavigableMap through a web application and I need to check if they're saved correctly. I tried to open the DB file but it's obviously unreadable.

Comment: Hi, have you ever found a way to read this? you can answer your own question.

Comment: You mean, read all data externally in some tool or through code?